# Git SC and Git source control provider SOS needed

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, git

I was building an application with VS 2010. I used the services of the Git source control system and the Git source control provider plugin. As i have finished 90% of the solution, i decided to make a huge change to the architecture of the application, so i deleted a couple of projects, files, added others and made all kinds of changes here and there in the solution. but before i did all that i made a commit to the whole solution. then when i decided to go back to that commit 50% or so of my hard work has gone. a lot of deleted files didn't come back, and some projects came back empty. Please i need help if there is any hope to restore my work. the history of commits is still there and i haven't touched the solution since.

Comment: Are you hosting your own Git server, or using a hosted service?  If you are using a service try contacting their support.  I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you without knowing a lot more detail than could be conveyed in a SO question.

Comment: @Jason, I am hosting my own Git server. i really don't know that much about git or source control in general, so i installed git for winodws and then installed Git source control provider and used the commands only from visual studio solution explorer.

Comment: Are you sure you rolled back to the right commit? Did you do your big architectural change on a new branch?

Comment: @DanielLee, yes i rolled back to right commit. as i have said, i don't know that much about source control or git. but i didn't do any branching, i did everything on what is called "master".

Comment: If you rolled back to the right commit then the files must be there. Files don't just disappear in git. Or did you not commit them? Did you remember to do a git add before committing? Maybe you should have look at your .gitignore file as well to check that you are not ignoring files that you want to keep.

Comment: @DanielLee, thank you for trying to help, i am not a git guru, nor i do know so much about source control. so i really can't diagnose why or how did this happen. i asked the question hoping that this might be caused by the Git Source Control Provider plugin for VS, and if it happened with some one else, then he could have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you have a backup to work with.
2. Try using `git fsck` from the command line to verify the integrity of your Git repository.

Comment: Thank you, i am backing up everything from now on, and the git repository integrity check looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Just a theory but maybe you lost your previous commit. If so then try git reflog (see [here](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html)) or follow this [guide](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html) for finding lost commits. If you committed the files then they should be there somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, but i haven't lost any commits, they are there.